# How to use JFrames or JWindows in an array

Tags: java, arrays, swing, jframe, jwindow

In my code I'm using over 100 predefined JWindows to play around with them over the screen : show or hide, move etc.
The definition looks like :

```
    public static JWindow R2 = new JWindow();
    public static JWindow R3 = new JWindow();
    public static JWindow S2 = new JWindow();
    public static JWindow S3 = new JWindow();

    R2.getContentPane().add(s0.labelNow("/testingPackage/" + "R2" + ".jpg"));
    R2.pack();
    R2.setLocation(10, 350);
    R2.setVisible(true);
    R3.getContentPane().add(s0.labelNow("/testingPackage/" + "R3" + ".jpg"));
    R3.pack();
    R3.setLocation(40, 350);
    R3.setVisible(true);
    S2.getContentPane().add(s0.labelNow("/testingPackage/" + "S2" + ".jpg"));
    S2.pack();
    S2.setLocation(550, 750);
    S2.setVisible(true);   etc.
```

As you can see this is resulting in a real mess of code, so I wonder if I could put the JWindows in an array or something similar, so that I could use something like 'JWArray[4][50]' and use loops to declare, define, move, show, hide them ?

Please find code below where I try to use an array of JWindows, which results in a null pointer exception on the line "JWA[i].getContentPane().add". I assumed this JWA[] declaration must be wrong.

```
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JWindow;

public class ShowPicture3 extends JPanel {

public static JWindow[] JWA = new JWindow[5];
public static ShowPicture3 s0 = new ShowPicture3();

public JLabel labelNow(String path) {
    ImageIcon imgIcon = new ImageIcon(ShowPicture3.class.getResource(path));
    JLabel label = new JLabel(imgIcon);
    add(label);
    return label;
}

public void prepareImages() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        System.out.println("/testingPackage/" + "R" + (i + 2) + ".jpg");
        s0.labelNow("/testingPackage/" + "R" + (i + 2) + ".jpg");
        JWA[i].getContentPane().add(s0.labelNow("/testingPackage/" + "R" + (i + 2) + ".jpg"));
        JWA[i].pack();
        JWA[i].setLocation(10 + i * 20, 350);
        JWA[i].setVisible(true);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    s0.prepareImages();
    JWA[0].setLocation(100, 750);
    JWA[2].setVisible(false);
}

}
```

Comment: `I'm using over 100 predefined JWindows` - I first question why you would want a 100 JWindows. Looks to me like you are just displaying a bunch of images. Why not just add the image to a JLabel and the label to a panel and the panel to a frame? `could put the JWindows in an array` - sure. An array can hold any object. Why would you think you couldn't do this? I suggest you try it and if you have problems you post a ]mcve] demonstrating the problem and ask a specific question.

Comment: Thx for reaction : I added one of my trials so far to the original question ...

Comment: By `]mcve]` @camickr actually meant `[mcve]` or (auto-expanded) [mcve]. Uncompilable code snippets do not make for an MCVE. BTW - you never explained *"I first question why you would want a 100 JWindows."*. See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) (The same is true of `JWindow`.)

Comment: And once again I repeat my question, why are you attempting to do this. You posted a snippet of code without any explanation of what it does. It appears you are trying to place images at specific locations on the screen. So why are you not use a JPanel with an appropriate layout manager to display those images?

Comment: @Andrew : thx for explanation, I added missing import statements, lower code in question should show error now when running.

Comment: @Andrew & camickr : it is the first time I work with JWindows and this seemed the most logic way of doing to me. While building further, I might change this if I get to know better alternatives. I can't learn it all at once ... The goal is to create a code that shows pictures on the screen, moves and/or hides them following the logic of the code and/or while listening to interventions of the user (mouseclicks).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to initialize the JWA array contents (its filled with nulls by default), just add "JWA[i] = new JWindow();" like in the example below.

```
public void prepareImages() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        JWA[i] = new JWindow();
        System.out.println("/testingPackage/" + "R" + (i + 2) + ".jpg");
        s0.labelNow("/testingPackage/" + "R" + (i + 2) + ".jpg");
        JWA[i].getContentPane().add(s0.labelNow("/testingPackage/" + "R" + (i + 2) + ".jpg"));
        JWA[i].pack();
        JWA[i].setLocation(10 + i * 20, 350);
        JWA[i].setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: tx Wojciech for yr help. I just don't see the difference with the line "public static JWindow[] JWA = new JWindow[5];" at the very beginning ? Doing the same with an array of integers or doubles works very well.

Comment: For primitives (ints, doubles) it works but for object types it doesn't. Array of objects is always initialized with nulls. Line "new JWindow[5]" just create an empty array of size 5. You must fill it with values :)